# Im having trouble making my animation work on the h1 element

Tags: css, animation

This is my code, including the animation in the CSS portion and the H1 element i want to apply it to.

[image: code image]

Comment: you should copy paste code snippets/errors instead of screenshots

Answer (score 0):

In fact, there's nothing wrong with the animation, but `left` doesn't have any impact on a static-positioned `h1` actually.

Have you tried to change that `left` to `margin-left`, or add `position: relative` to h1? Like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/x6JythFhtrF8UFeqKtyG?p=preview

Plus, I believe you wanna make it run infinitely, otherwise the `alternate` cannot be observed, therefore you might wanna put in `infinite` as the `animation-iteration-count`

```
h1 {
  position: relative; /* TRY TO ADD THIS */
  animation: enter 5s linear alternate infinite; /* OPTIONAL infinite */ 
}
@keyframes enter {
  from {
    left: 0em;
  }
  to {
    left: 20em;
  }
}
```